# Built-In fields do not show up on real device

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I use Azure AD B2C to authenticate users on my Xamarin.Forms app. The Sign Up screen has only 3 entry fields: Email Address, New Password, and Confirm New Password. I need to add First and Last Name fields, which I did in B2C_1_BlazorSignup user flow -> Page Layouts -> Local account sign up page. It looks like this:

[image]

When I run user flow on the portal, the result looks as expected:

[image]

And yet the additional fields do not show up on the real device, including Display Name field that was in the list before I added Given Name and Surname.

Also, how can I rename Given Name to First Name and Surname to Last Name?

Comment: I'm not sure on the Xamarin portion, but you can change the `Label` of the User Attributes in the Page Layout. Simply click on the Attribute, and change the `Label` field (all the way to the right).

Comment: @BradC. Thanks, this part works! I do need this to be reflected in the device... I don't know if it has anything to do with my code in Xamarin.Forms, or should be somehow set in Azure portal...

Comment: @BradC. Figured it out, I was just in a wrong spot. But your suggestion was a real help. If you make it your answer, I will mark it as such. Thanks again.

Comment: @BradC.  Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the labels of the User Attributes, select the **Page Layout** in the Azure B2C Portal, and then click the attribute. Once there, you should be able to modify the `Label` field on the far right of the screen.